# I added a WebView to my Cocoa app and it's generating an error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I added a WebView to my app and I'm loading a page into it using this code:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    NSString *resourcesPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    NSString *htmlPath = [resourcesPath stringByAppendingString:@"/calendarHTML/test.html"];
    [[webView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlPath]]]; 
}
```

However, when I run the app I receive the following error:

```
Layout still needs update after calling -[WebHTMLView layout].  
WebHTMLView or one of its superclasses may have overridden 
-layout without calling super. Or, something may have dirtied 
layout in the middle of updating it.  Both are programming errors in 
Cocoa Autolayout.  The former is pretty likely to arise if some 
pre-Cocoa Autolayout class had a method called layout, but it should be fixed.!
```

[image: error log]

What is causing this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that the nib containing the window that you have placed the WebView into is using the new [Auto Layout](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html) feature, introduced in Lion.

When a nib file has auto layout enabled, the window will call the `-layout` method on all `NSView` objects in the window.

This causes a problem with `WebView` because it had a method named `-layout` before it the method was added to the `NSView` API in Lion, and `WebView`'s `layout` method does not understand auto layout.

Probably the best fix for the time being is to use the old autoresizing mask method of laying out the views in your window. As Xcode now creates nib files with autolayout enabled, you need to disable it yourself.

You can do that in the File inspector for your nib file, by disabling the `Use Auto Layout` checkbox.

[image: interface builder inspector]

After you do this, you'll need to make sure that all the views in the nib have the correct autoresizing settings in the Size tab of the view inspector.

Answer (score 3):

Note that you can safely ignore that log message for WebViews.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the case of `WebView` but If you are using any custom class (like subclass of `UILabel`) and you are using the method :

```
- (void)updateConstraints
{

}
```

then definitely It will crash your app. Best solution is to remove this method and write your required changes in '`awakeFromNib`' method. Hope this help someone else who is getting this crash in custom class.